# Vuedraggable how to swap item between 2 draggable

Tags: vuejs3, vuedraggable

[image]

Hi all, i have a problem in vuedraggable. When i drag "item 2" to "item 3" => I want "item 3" will swap with "item 2".
Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple lists and each list has its own `<draggable>` element, then you will need to assign a new method `handleMove(event)` to your `<draggable>` elements. The `event` parameter is important because `event.draggedContext` contains the index of the item that you are trying to move (`index`) and also the index of the other item which is currently overlapping with your grabbed item (`futureIndex`). It also contains information from which list is your grabbed item (`event.from`) and where you want to drop it (`event.to`). Store these 4 variables somewhere and use them when you are done dragging (function `handleDragEnd()`).

Inside `handleDragEnd()` simply swap those 2 items and Vue will update the HTML template.

**[LIVE DEMO HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-app-zspw1h?file=src/App.vue)**

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>My LEGO Bionicles</h3>
      <draggable
        class="list-group"
        data-list="list1"
        :list="list1"
        group="bionicles"
        @change="log"
        itemKey="id"
        :move="handleMoveItem"
        @end="handleDragEndItem"
        :options="{ animation: 500 }"
      >
        <template #item="{ element, index }">
          <div class="list-group-item" :style="element.style">
            {{ element.name }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </draggable>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>Favourite LEGO Bionicle</h3>
      <draggable
        class="list-group"
        data-list="list2"
        :list="list2"
        group="bionicles"
        @change="log"
        itemKey="id"
        :move="handleMoveItem"
        @end="handleDragEndItem"
        :options="{ animation: 500 }"
      >
        <template #item="{ element, index }">
          <div class="list-group-item" :style="element.style">
            {{ element.name }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </draggable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';
export default {
  name: 'two-lists-swap',
  display: 'Swapping between 2 lists',
  order: 1,
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      list1: [
        { name: 'TOA Mata Nui', id: 1, style: { background: 'gold' } },
        {
          name: 'TOA Tahu',
          id: 2,
          style: { background: 'red', color: 'yellow' },
        },
        { name: 'TOA Kopaka', id: 3, style: { background: 'white' } },
        {
          name: 'TOA Anakin',
          id: 4,
          style: { background: 'black', color: 'yellow' },
        },
      ],
      list2: [
        {
          name: 'TOA Gali',
          id: 5,
          style: { background: 'blue', color: 'yellow' },
        },
        {
          name: 'TOA Lewa',
          id: 6,
          style: { background: 'green', color: 'yellow' },
        },
        {
          name: 'TOA Pohatu',
          id: 7,
          style: { background: 'brown', color: 'white' },
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleDragEndItem() {
      if (this.originalList === this.futureList) {
        this.movingItem = this[this.futureList][this.originalIndex];
        this.futureItem = this[this.futureList][this.futureIndex];

        if (this.movingItem && this.futureItem) {
          let _list = Object.assign([], this[this.futureList]);
          _list[this.futureIndex] = this.movingItem;
          _list[this.originalIndex] = this.futureItem;
          this[this.futureList] = _list;
        }
      } else {
        this.movingItem = this[this.originalList][this.originalIndex];
        this.futureItem = this[this.futureList][this.futureIndex];

        if (this.movingItem && this.futureItem) {
          let _listFrom = Object.assign([], this[this.originalList]);
          let _listTo = Object.assign([], this[this.futureList]);
          _listTo[this.futureIndex] = this.movingItem;
          _listFrom[this.originalIndex] = this.futureItem;
          this[this.originalList] = _listFrom;
          this[this.futureList] = _listTo;
        }
      }
      document
        .querySelectorAll('.list-group-item')
        .forEach((el) => (el.style.border = 'none'));
      this.$toast.show('dragEnd');
    },
    handleMoveItem(event) {
      document
        .querySelectorAll('.list-group-item')
        .forEach((el) => (el.style.border = 'none'));
      const { index, futureIndex } = event.draggedContext;
      this.originalIndex = index;
      this.futureIndex = futureIndex;
      this.originalList = event.from.getAttribute('data-list');
      this.futureList = event.to.getAttribute('data-list');
      if (this[this.futureList][this.futureIndex]) {
        event.to.children[this.futureIndex].style.border = '2px solid orange';
      }
      return false; // disable sort
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>
.list-group-item {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: grab;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, but i have 2 or 3 list draggable and i want swap between 2 list. not just 1 list. can u help me this case?

Comment: @Maruko I have updated the answer also for swapping between 2 lists, the logic is the same at the core, you will only need to look up how things are done with Vuedraggable if there are multiple lists.

Comment: awesome, thanks u so much