# Vue draggable swapping and vue-split-layout want to use for same list

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Want to use both Vue draggable for swapping and vue-split-layout for resizing. both individually work but not together for same list.. can you help code for resize the split panels and swapping items

Tired both together but not working.. individually works fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69646082/vuedraggable-how-to-swap-item-between-2-draggable/69647728#69647728?newreg=f112e1b7e74e4182943560cf8fc16dc0 related to this